# Cambiar booleanos por texto

Tags: javascript, json, objeto

```
const json = [
{
nombre: "michell",
tieneDeporteFavorito: true
},
{
nombre: "juan",
tieneDeporteFavorito: true
},
{
nombre: "carlos",
tieneDeporteFavorito: false
}
]
```

tengo esta funcion en javascript pero necesito porder saber hay otra manera mejor de trabajar con los objectos

```
function cambiarBoolean(json ){
  const renombrar = [];

  for(let dato of json){
      if(dato ){
        let converString = dato .toString().toLowerCase().replace(/true/gi, 'si')
         renombrar.push(converString)
      }else{
        let converString = correo.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/false/gi, 'no')
        renombrar.push(converString)
     
      }
    
  }
   return renombrar  

}
```

necesito poder cambiar los boolean por texto si me pueden mejorar mi codigo se lo agredezco

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres como resultado final es un arreglo con la forma

```
   [`sí`, `sí`, `no`]
```

Entonces tu función puede resolverse en una línea

```
function cambiarBoolean(json ){
     return json.map(entry => entry.tieneDeporteFavorito ? 'sí' : 'no')
}
```